# how do I assign a function to an element of an array of function pointers

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, function-pointers

In Xcode 7.2.1, I declare 3 C functions

```
double function1(double);
double function2(double);
double function3(double);
```

Now I declare a pointer to a function and define it.

```
double (*aFunctionPointer)(double)=function1;
```

No errors, as expected.

Now I declare an array of function pointers and fill it with my 3 functions.

```
double (*anArrayOfFunctionPointers[3])(double)={function1, function2, function3};
```

Again, no errors.

Now I define an array of function pointers, but do not fill it.

```
double (*anotherArrayOfFunctionPointers[3])(double);
```

Again, no errors.

Now I try to assign a function to one of the array elements.

```
anotherArrayOfFunctionPointers[1]=function2;
```

This time, warnings and errors:

- Warning: Type specifier missing, defaults to int
- Error: Redefinition of 'anotherArrayOfFunctionPointers' with a different type:'int [0]' vs 'double (*[3]) (double)'

I am stumped.

The background is that I am trying to write a program to convert between various units of measure. I thought I would use a two-dimensional array containing function pointers, in order to avoid a number of very lengthy switch statements.

To make a conversion, I would call a function as follows:

```
result=convert(someValueToConvert,yards,meters);
```

and the convert function would invoke the correct function from the array like so:

```
return conversionFunctionArray[yards, meters](someValue);
```

The array would be initialized like so:

```
conversionFunction[yards][meters]=yardsToMeters(somevalue);
conversionFunction[meters][yards]=metersToYards(somevalue);
conversionFunction[yards][feet]=yardsToFeet...
...
```

What am I missing as regards function pointers and arrays?

Comment: `typedef` is a very useful tool when dealing with function pointers.  Try something like `typedef double (*funcPtr_t)(double);` to create a function pointer type, then something like `funcPtr_t funcPtrArray[3];` for your array.

Comment: The error clearly states that you've **redefined** anotherArrayOfFunctionPointers. So somewhere in your test code you have an older definition of that array.  Note that I followed all of your instructions line by line, and did not get any errors or warnings. That's why the site requires that debugging questions must include a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) looks like for this question, based on the piecemeal instructions in the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double f1( double );
double f2( double );
double f3( double );

int main( void )
{
    // testing a single function pointer
    double (*ptr1)(double) = f1;
    printf( "%.0lf\n\n", (*ptr1)(5) );

    // testing an array of function pointers with an initializer list
    double (*array[3])(double) = { f1, f2, f3 };
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        printf( "%.0lf\n", (*array[i])(6) );
    printf( "\n" );

    // testing an array of function pointers that is initialized by assignments
    double (*otherArray[3])(double);
    otherArray[0] = f1;
    otherArray[1] = f2;
    otherArray[2] = f3;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        printf( "%.0lf\n", (*otherArray[i])(7) );
    printf( "\n" );
}

double f1( double x ) { return 10+x; }
double f2( double x ) { return 20+x; }
double f3( double x ) { return 30+x; }
```

Note that this code compiles without any errors or warnings, and produces the expected output. Demonstrating once again why debugging questions **must** include a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

One obvious problem is that you have not actually defined any of the functions `function1` etc.

To see this, let's do this with just *one* function and with arrays of just *one* element. Put this at top level:

```
double function1(double);
double (*aFunctionPointer)(double)=function1;
double (*anArrayOfFunctionPointers[1])(double)={function1};
double (*anotherArrayOfFunctionPointers[1])(double);
```

And in actual executable code, do this:

```
anotherArrayOfFunctionPointers[0]=function1; // error
```

That's an error. But now let's actually *define* `function1`, like this:

```
double function1(double f) {return 3.0;};
double (*aFunctionPointer)(double)=function1;
double (*anArrayOfFunctionPointers[1])(double)={function1};
double (*anotherArrayOfFunctionPointers[1])(double);
```

And now let's try the same code:

```
anotherArrayOfFunctionPointers[0]=function1;
```

No error. The difference is that now we actually *have* a `function1` to point to. With *your* code, there's no there there.

Comment: By the way, stylistically, when you are passing function pointers around, you might like to use the ampersand: `&function1`. This is absolutely not necessary, but I find it makes for clarity of intention.